# Yii configuration and git: how to manage sensitive information securely?

Tags: git, yii

What is the common practice for keeping passwords and other sensitive information out of the repository when using a version control system like git for web-application done with Yii framework?

The obvious solution is to add a whole configuration file to *.gitignore*, but it leaves a web application boneless after all.

Answer (score 2):

- Split the configuration file into multiple ones
- Set default values and no sensitive data into the configuration files that DO get included in GIT
- Set sensitive data and custom parameters in files that get Ignored in Git

I have a setup like this for a project built with Yii 1, but could be adapted yo Yii2 basic too.

Yii 2 advanced has already the environment functionality and ignores some local config files by default and I think it should be adapted and used.

Anyways, here goes the example for Yii 1:

File list:

```
protected/config/main.php
protected/config/params.php
protected/config/custom.params.php // ignored
protected/config/import.php
protected/config/db.common.php
protected/config/db.example.php
protected/config/db.php // ignored
```

Contents of `protected/config/main.php`:

```
<?php

$params = require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/params.php');

if (file_exists(dirname(__FILE__) . '/custom.params.php')) {
  $params = CMap::mergeArray($params, require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/custom.params.php'));
}

$config= array(
  // ...
  'import' => require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/import.php'),
  'modules' => array(
    // ...
  ),
  // application components
  'components' => array(
    // ...
    'db' => require(dirname(__FILE__) . '/db.common.php'),
  ),
  'params' => $params,
);

return $config;
```

Contents of `protected/config/db.common.php`:

```
<?php

return CMap::mergeArray(
    array(
        'emulatePrepare' => true,
        'enableProfiling' => true,
        'enableParamLogging' => true,
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'tablePrefix' => '', 
    ),
    require(dirname(__FILE__).'/db.php') 
);
```

Contents of `protected/config/db.example.php`:

```
<?php

return array(
    'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=yii_db',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
);
```

How you use it:

- After cloning your project, it will break because you have no `db.php` config file
- So you copy/paste `db.example.php` to `db.php` and customize it
- You optionally can create a `custom.params.php` file if you want to customize your current application params locally
- In `db.commpn.php` you have defaults for the db component, and in `db.php` you have sensitive data